# Error using UTL_MAIL in a SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, email, plsql, utl-mail

I am attempting to send an email using a sql procedure, and am getting some errors.  Here is my relevant code:

```
   IF cur_email%FOUND THEN
stu_email := schema.get_person_email_adr(v_id);

 IF send_email = 'Y' THEN

UTL_MAIL.SEND (sender => v_email_from,     -- line of error
               recipients => stu_email,
               subject => v_email_subject,
               mime_type => 'text/html',
               message => v_email_body );
END IF;
END IF;
```

I will be getting multiple "v_id", and am trying to send an email to each one that I get, so I was also wondering if I am doing that correctly?  The error that I am getting is this:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_MAIL' must be declared
```

I am not sure why I am encountering this, Before I made some of these changes, I never received this error, so I believe that the utl_mail set up is not the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You are talking about utl_file, but yet your code shows utl_mail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTL_MAIL is not installed by default, because it requires some configuring on the part of the sysadmin team.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm).

So, perhaps it has not been installed, or perhaps EXECUTE privilege on it has not been granted to your stored procedure owner.

Comment: I had just come back to this page to mark my question as answered, because I didnt grant execute to my schema on the utl_mail package, haha.  So, good timing, appreciate the help.